# problem trying to integrate firebase to android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I trying integrate FireBase in Android Studio.
But, when i get to this point:

```
allprojects{

    repositories
    {
        google()
    }
}
```

They give me:

**Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'**

But, if i don´t write these repositories, i can sync.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFwSg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFwSg.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, check in your gradle scripts,

1. if you have settings.gradle file then do like below in settigs.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Schedule Post"
include ':app'
```

2. if you don't have settings.gradle then your build.gradle(Project level) look like below code.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta